ASP .NET Backend authorization middleware does not work when started with VS-Code, but works when started with "dotnet run"
Some prerequisite information:
dotnet version:
7.0.36
Now to my problem:
I was working on my project which makes use of Angular in the frontend and C# in the backend. I have added Authorization and Authentication using JWT Bearer tokens.
After receiving the token when i logged in, i created an Angular Interceptor that sends the token every time a request is sent.
What confused me is:
QUESTION 1: Why do I receive 401 unauthorized despite having sent the request in the right format?
What is even weirder: I ONLY get 401 unauthorized when i start my backend with Visual studio code (via launch.json), but when i start my backend via the command line "dotnet run", my requests do finally work.
QUESTION 2: Why? What is the difference between starting with launch.json / CMD line?
I can't figure it out on my own, I only accidently found out that this is the source of my error.
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program":     "${workspaceFolder}/recipe_backend/bin/Debug/net7.0/recipe_backend.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/recipe_backend",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}

Program.cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using recipe_backend.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// DB Connection
var versionNumber = builder.Configuration.GetSection("DB_Version").Get<int[]>();
var version = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(versionNumber[0],versionNumber[1],versionNumber[2]));
var connectionStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FullStackConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RecipesDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionStr, version));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new IngredientTypeConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TimeUnitConverter());
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


I used Postman instead of Angular to send my request with the valid token.
Here, it worked on both cases:
lauch.json with Visal studio code AND manually with the command line
In Angular, I send the token by using an Interceptor. I double checked that the token I received wasn't manipulated such that authorization wouldn't work (which would be weird giving the fact that using my frontend, authorization works when I start my backend with dotnet run).
I am glad that authorization works at least starting with my command line, but this would make debugging a bit more tedious, because using VS Code debugger helps me quite well.

I logged the middleware, too, i always receive:
These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged

I might be shooting blanks here, but did you check your firewall? It has happened to me a few times that a program wouldn't run correctly when running from an IDE, and the firewall was enabled, but there were no problems in the console.
